# Clicking a div in a browser opened from runs in Python

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I have been trying to automate a process for myself that basically clicks in a lot of things in a webpages.

I tried using pyAutoGui to find what I need and do the clicking and typing. The problem I found is that if screen resolution or browser display size is changed in any way, it stops working (it compares a reference image with a screenshot it takes). So currently I need something that finds the html element position and clicks it (pyAutoGui hands the clicking if needed).

The main problem is that I need to open Internet Explorer using runas, because each time the program runs, it is with a different user.
I see many people suggesting using web kits that open their own browser sessions, but I don't know if they would be able to run as different user.

Can anyone shine some light on the matter?

edit: Some Code.

The function that finds the reference image on screen (only working if image is  pixel perfect)

```
def FindImageAndClick(ImagePath:str, numberOfTries:int):
    counter = 0
    while counter <numberOfTries:
        try:
            x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(ImagePath, grayscale=True)
            print('encontrado posicoes x='+str(x)+' e y='+str(y))
            break
        except:
            time.sleep(2.0)
            counter += 1
    if counter==numberOfTries:
        return False
    pyautogui.moveTo(x,y)
    pyautogui.click()
    return True
```

Opening IE using runas (user credential provided when the program started):

```
iePath='"'+ '\\'+'"'+os.getenv("SystemDrive")+'\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe\\'+'"'
website = corporate website
print (iePath + website)
o = subprocess.Popen('runas.exe /user:domain\%s %s %s' %(currentUser, iePath, website))
time.sleep(1.0)
pyautogui.typewrite(currentPassword)
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

Jus reiterating that the program works as intended as long as the resolution, browser zoom level, etc remain the same.

Comment: Do you have any current code? Please include your code so we can help you fix it.

Comment: Currently on mobile, I will add the code as soon as I return to my desk. But it is basically pyautogui calls, comparing with reference images (pyautogui. Findcenteronscreen(referenceimage). Those work if I screenshot what I want and reference it, but stop working if screen resolution changes.

Comment: added some code @HyperNeutrino